# Undo effects of running ntfsfix (ntfs-3g) on a Windows NTFS partition

Tags: partitioning, mount, ntfs, ntfs-3g

Using Ubuntu I was trying to access an NTFS partition that was created using the partition tool in Windows.

Then I took the decision of running ntfsfix on it.

I got access to another exfat partition(sdb5) that was not put through ntfsfix simply by accessing the drive from a Windows machine but the newly NTFS partition wont open saying the 'partition is corrupted and unreadable'.

Comment: Typically all ntfsfix does is turn on the chkdsk flag, so Windows will run chkdsk. Have you run chkdsk on the partition?

Comment: @oldfred I ran chkdsk but it couldn't do anything. Running chkdsk gave: Unable to determine volume version and state.  CHKDSK aborted.

Comment: This is a Windows NTFS issue. And Ask Ubuntu is about Ubuntu. refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic